# How to check no argument is given to argparse in python?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using python to parse arguments. What I want to do is to check if there is no arguments given. However, parse_args() returns a namespace object.
Currently, I have to transfer the namespace to a dict, and check the value sets if there is one non-None element.
I want to know if there is any simple way to do so.

Comment: Depending on how you define your arguments, this can show up as an error or one or more empty slots in the namespace set to their default values.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is just check the length of `sys.argv[1:]`.

Comment: Your current solution does not know whether an arg was provided by "default" or explicitly.  I think if the args namespace is not with sufficient information, then maybe you are setting up the arg parser poorly in the first place.

Comment: For most Action classes, `None` is the default.  `if args.myarg is None:` is a good test (you don't have go through the `dict` to do that test).  You users can't enter `None` as a value.  The other option is to define a meaningful `default`, and not worry whether the argument was given or not.  But if you want to check whether any argument was given (as opposed to a particular one), just look at `sys.argv[1:]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse_args()` does not depopulate `sys.argv`. Therefore, `len(sys.argv) == 1` is a good proxy for a no-argument check (since `sys.argv` still has a length of 1 when no arguments are passed).